# Force object in array to the end preserving current logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that sorts via its `sortId`. If there isn't a `sortId` i.e a null value, then the null values keep there original order between them but the items with a `sortId` take priority over the null values in the overall outpout/order. This has already been implemented.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sorting-aguwqn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

What I need to do now is look at the array length and any `sortId` thats greater than the array length then push it to the end.

**.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  fieldsList = new Array();
  users = [
    {
      user: 'fred',
      arrayPosition: 1,
      sortId: null
    },
    {
      user: 'Gen',
      arrayPosition: 2,
      sortId: null
    },
    {
      user: 'Billy',
      arrayPosition: 3,
      sortId: 4
    },
    {
      user: 'Sid',
      arrayPosition: 4,
      sortId: 5
    },
    {
      user: 'James',
      arrayPosition: 5,
      sortId: null
    },
    {
      user: 'Tom',
      arrayPosition: 6,
      sortId: 1
    },
    {
      user: 'Jim',
      arrayPosition: 7,
      sortId: 99
    },
    {
      user: 'Steve',
      arrayPosition: 8,
      sortId: null
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fieldsList = [...this.users];
    Array(this.fieldsList.length)
      .fill('1')
      .forEach((_, index) => {
        let user;
        let oldIndex;
        this.fieldsList.some((u, i) => {

          if(+u.sortId === index + 1) {
            user = u;
            oldIndex = i;
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        })
        const newIndex = +user?.sortId - 1;
        this.fieldsList.splice(newIndex, 0, user);
        this.fieldsList.splice(oldIndex + 1, 1)
      });
  }
}
```

In the demo you will see that 99 is in row 7 and there is a null behind it in row 8. This is because 99 is the last `sortId` number and numbers come before null values. This is all as expected.

What I want is 99 or any number greater than the array length to be last regardless of previous priority and logic.

I think it needs to be `.slice`(ed) out and then `.concat` back into the end array.

Comment: I don't understand the expected in `stackblitz`.

Comment: also your first `null` Id is moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the length of the array to be sorted as a cut-off value resulting in a single condition sort comparison.

To properly sort `null` values against actual values that are equal-to or one-greater-than `array.length` we adjust the value assigned by the relationship of the other value to `array.length`

```js
const users = [{ user: 'Billy', arrayPosition: 3, sortId: 4 }, { user: 'fred', arrayPosition: 1, sortId: null }, { user: 'Gen', arrayPosition: 2, sortId: null }, { user: 'Sid', arrayPosition: 4, sortId: 5 }, { user: 'James', arrayPosition: 5, sortId: null }, { user: 'Tom', arrayPosition: 6, sortId: 1 }, { user: 'Jim', arrayPosition: 7, sortId: 99 }, { user: 'Steve', arrayPosition: 8, sortId: null }];

users.sort(({ sortId: a }, { sortId: b }) => {
  const a_ = a ?? users.length + (b <= users.length);
  const b_ = b ?? users.length + (a <= users.length);

  return (a_ - users.length) - (b_ - users.length)
});

console.log(users.map(({ sortId, arrayPosition }) => ({ arrayPosition, sortId })));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this'll work, I've not tested it myself.

```
const oldArray = // data here

const newArray = oldArray.concat(oldArray.slice(0, 1)).shift()
```

`concat` should add the first element of the array to the end using `slice(0, 1)` and afterwards you `shift` the whole array to remove the first item.

Answer (score 0):

It feels rather error-prone and unnecessarily complicated to "sort" an array by manually using forEach/splice.

The built-in [sort with a custom compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#parameters) should do just fine:

```
var origArr = [...users];
users.sort(function(a,b) {
  // move to end if > arr-length
  if (a.sortId > users.length) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (b.sortId > users.length) {
    return -1;
  }

  // sort by sortId
  if (a.sortId && b.sortId) {
    return a.sortId - b.sortId;
  }

  // only 1 item has a sortId
  if (a.sortId) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b.sortId) {
    return 1;
  }

  // between els with both NULL keep the orig sorting
  return origArr.indexOf(a) - origArr.indexOf(b);
});
```

I hope this is the order you intended (it is what I understood from your text), your text and the "expected order" from the example site don't quite match imo / you even have 2x origpos 7 in there. :

```
[
  { user: 'Tom', arrayPosition: 6, sortId: 1 },
  { user: 'Billy', arrayPosition: 3, sortId: 4 },
  { user: 'Sid', arrayPosition: 4, sortId: 5 },
  { user: 'fred', arrayPosition: 1, sortId: null },
  { user: 'Gen', arrayPosition: 2, sortId: null },
  { user: 'James', arrayPosition: 5, sortId: null },
  { user: 'Steve', arrayPosition: 8, sortId: null },
  { user: 'Jim', arrayPosition: 7, sortId: 99 }
]
```

Comment: `null` sortId should not be moved, I think

Comment: The link suggests so yes. But they wrote "items with a sortId take priority over the null values" and "null values keep there original order between them"

Comment: Then your answer may be the best one.

Comment: That is what I expect yes... having trouble adding this to my blitz example.